# Apply Options > "Assign to" - "All Desktop" only to 1 chrome tab?

Tags: macos

I keep my task list with rememberthemilk.com and I would like to have keep that chrome tab opened at all spaces all the time. Is there a way to achieve this?

Right now if I go to chrome and Assign to All Desktop for it I am seeing other chrome windows being brought to the front when I switch spaces.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible natively. The desktop assignments are on a per-app basis, and not customizable by window.

A workaround could be to use [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/), whereby you could create an actual application for the web app. This application could be assigned to all spaces.